# WPF Firing the RoutedEvents with a Delay

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I am gathering all the routed events fired for the MouseRightDownButton and storing them in a Queue. I have the Sender object as well as the RoutedEventArgs.

Now, I need to fire those events one by one and with a little pause. I also want to update the UI as I fire each event.

Do this require the Timer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will require a timer of some sort. I would check out the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) class if you need to update objects on the UI.

Comment: Thanks! I was using Timer and it was having problem with UI object update. Dispatcher seems to be working fine! Thanks